# How to compress video from a PCL in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, compression

I´m doing a "Whatsapp" like app and I need to send user videos (from camera/gallery).

I need to send video from ios to android and from android to ios (windows phone in the future).

First thing I thought is to use camera params to record the video in low resolution, but that won´t help with recorded videos stored in the phone already.

Second thought was to zip the video file, but I guess this is not enough for very large files.

Third: actually compressing the video file generating a new file, and then zip it before sending it through the network.

So this is what I need before actually sending the video:

1. Compress the video file, generating a new file that will play nicely in
   both platforms (ios and android)
2. Make the compressing process aysnc(as I don´t want to block the UI
   thread for a really long time)
3. Zip it (this is the easy part, just for the record)

Any ideas or help are appreciated

Comment: zipping a compressed video stream isn't going to do much.   And you will probably need to use each platform's native video capability to do the compression.  I don't think you will find a ready-made pure cross platform solution.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I will then look into native video compression. This could be a nice opportunity to build that cross platform library, but that will be hard I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You would best need to use your platforms framework to also leverage existing hardware support for encoding (mainly h.264 hardware encoding). A PCL solution would eat to much battery as it would need to run on CPU only giving you bad performance and even worst battery live.
2. This ties in with 1. Just use your platforms native method to execute the frameworks methods async.
3. Skip this part. It will increase overhead and disallow video streaming There are virtually 0 benefits from using a zip algorithm on top of an already compressed video stream.

Just make sure that you end up with a cross platform compatible video format like H264.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you say I´ll have to implement this on each platform. To make it easier I´ll create a PCL utility to proxy the platform code